# How to see description by clicking on recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

all devlopers

See i want to go in other activity which shows the description of clicked item in recycler view ;I know how to do ....we can do by Intent put extra. But my problem is we can put extra those all data which lies on cardview but i want to send data to another activity which is not in the cardview of item of recycler view .like discription of item
So how to do ,please can anyone explain me?
Thank you

Comment: Share all the data available in adapter and among them which you want to share in another activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you had set event navigate to another activity (`startActivity`) inside adapter.

You should let `startActivity` in your activity class, and when recyclerview item click, just invoke callback.

Example:

1. Create your interface

```
public interface YourListener {

    /**
     * This method will invoke when button of recyclerview item click
    **/
    void navigateToAnotherActivityWithData(String data);
}
```

2. Put listener event to your adapter

```
class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
    private YourListener mListener;
    private String dataOfRecyclerView;

    public YourAdapter(YourListener listener) {
        this.mListener = listener;
    }
    ...
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
     
         holder.btnNext.setOnClickListener(v-> {
             if(mListener != null) 
                 mListener.navigateToAnotherActivityWithData(dataOfRecyclerView);
         });
      ...
    }
    ...
}
```

3. Define event action in your activity. And you can send data from both recyclerview and activity.

```
        adapter = new YourAdapter(data -> {
           Intent intent = Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
           intent.putExtra("DATA_OF_RECYCLERVIEW", data);
           intent.putExtra(...);
           ...
        });
```

Comment: got it ...tx ,but can we do perfect this things when we retrive data from firebase and set on recycler view at that time can we share data from model class???? My mean can we share the data of model class by intent.putExtra(...) To another activity ??will it send those data of item which we have clicked?

Comment: You can work around as convert your list data of activity A to string by gson and use putExtra. Then in B you convert it to your data again. But it's not good for your app performance.

Comment: Another solution you can research and consider:
`
- Fetch data again in activity B
- Store data in singleton and clear this data when you no more use.
- Store data in model layer, your activity use viewmodel for fetch data, your viewmodel fetch data from firebase (remote) or sqlite (local).
- Use gson to convert json
- Use static instance in Application class
`